# Can't click on element rendered via AJAX

Tags: javascript, casperjs

The header content is render via Ajax:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var loadingTimer = setInterval(animate_loading, 66);
                $.post('home/load_header', {}, function(data) {
                    clearInterval(loadingTimer);            
                    $("#header_content").html(data);              
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I am trying to reach `.switch_language` but there is no such thing in the html when I check in `CTR+U` window. There is only the JS above. The `.switch_language` exist but only can find it within the `F12/ELements` tab. Tried with `wait(SECONDS)`, `waitForSelector` as well. Every-time `Cannot dispatch click event on non-existing element`.

Comment: Maybe include the code where you attach the click event? I bet it's a race condition.

Comment: add the code where you are trying to get it.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL+U is View Page Source, which shows the server-side HTML sent to your browser. It does not contain the structure of the live DOM and anything that changed AFTER the page is served to you -- meaning anything that is changed by JavaScript or asynchronous events like Ajax.

For the live DOM, you should use the Web Inspector (or equivalent... different browsers call it slightly different things -- it's DevTools in Chrome).

Since you are using JQuery, you can attach events to elements that don't yet exist w/ live().

Comment: Do not use the [.live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/) API, it was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in jQuery 1.9. Instead use the [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) API. If you need to attach an event that does not exist when your JS is executed, you'll want to use a [delegated event handler](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). For this issue, that essentially means running something like `$(document).on('click', '.switch_language', function(event) { ... });`

Comment: Good catch on live() vs on(). You are correct. I recently did some support work on a site w/ jQuery 1.7, so that's what came to mind first.